# Cartesian representation of a unit sphere

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Looking through related questions, there do not appear to be equivalent questions.  Note, this question came from what appears to be more information available in the Unit sphere, and a perhaps natural representation in Cartesian coordinates. The question is whether or not a constrained approach with Cartesian coordinates would provide a user with an intuitive method for rotations.

In considering a representation of a unit sphere, Cartesian coordinates are unable to carry the spherical representation of $\theta\ through\ Z\ \epsilon\ \{-1, 1\}$, unlike spherical coordinates.

This is "gimbal lock," in which any value of $\theta$ solves the equation, and so as rotations traverse $Z \epsilon \{-1, 1\}, \theta$ is lost.

Meanwhile, in a spherical representation of the unit sphere: $\{1=radius, \theta, \phi\}, \theta$ can be maintained through a rotation by using $\phi$ as the elevation, and deriving $\theta$ from any values of x and y.

A Cartesian representation of the unit sphere is intuitive. The rotation of a shape is pointed at $\overrightarrow\xyz$, on a unit sphere.

The question is whether it is intuitive enough to replace Cartesian coordinates with a modification to allow $\theta\ and\ \phi$ to be determined.

In this case, $\phi$ as indicated by $Z$ is used as an absolute to determine the elevation, with $Z \epsilon [-1, 1]\ and\ x\ and\ y$ any value to determine $\theta$.
In this case, as $Z \epsilon \{ -1, 1 \},\ x\ and\ y \ values\ can\ be\ used\ to\ determine\ \theta$ in spherical coordinates, though they do not change the location on the unit sphere.

Perhaps, it is simply better to use spherical coordinates of $\{radius, \theta, \phi\}$, which can carry $\theta$ through the otherwise undefined areas.

Note, this question comes from what seems to be more information associated with spherical coordinates, the additional information they provide around inflection points, and a method to resolve with modified Cartesian coordinates on the unit sphere.

The question is, is it intuitive enough, on a unit sphere, to add additional context to the $\{x, y\}$ portion of $\{x, y, z\}$ for $z \epsilon \{-1, 1\}$ to replace spherical coordinates with Cartesian coordinates?

Comment: Can we say that your question is about a cartesian sphere coordinate system $(x=..., y=..., z=...)$ warranting a bijection ?

Comment: Don’t really know what you’re asking, but try this paper and their references. https://vvise.iat.sfu.ca/user/data/papers/comparerotation.pdf

Comment: I'm also having trouble understanding the question; context suggests it's about an "improved" coordinate system of some type that can handle or avoid gimbal lock?

Comment: I didn't understand this was unclear.  It's not about an improved Cartesian coordinate system, but one modified for the unit sphere.  For all but $Z\epsilon\{1,-1\}$, the $\overarrowxyz$ have a magnitude of 1.  For $Z\epsilon\{1, -1\},$ $x, y$  defines $\theta ; x, y\epsilon \mathbb{R}$.  In a normal Cartesian representation, theta at the poles can not be determined.  This allows a rotation vector to be uniquely determined.

Comment: @bubba, thanks for the pointer.  It's interesting in that it too seems to be trying to solve a similar problem.  In thinking about this, for unit sphere representations, I suspect it is easier to use spherical coordinates: $\{1, \theta, \phi\}$, as it's consistent.  Experimentation with an implementation indicates that "poles" are not always at $\phi \epsilon\{0,180\}$. That would require $\phi$ to always indicate elevation, and $x, y$ to always indicate $\theta$, so there is zero gain.

Comment: You get into gimbal lock at the poles because the $\theta$ in spherical coordinates is discontinuous there. That is a property of spherical coordinates and as long as you use spherical coordinates there's no way to "fix" it. You can use rotation matrices or quaternions for rotations in space and never use spherical coordinates at all -- I mean never, ever ask what the spherical coordinates are -- and then you won't have gimbal lock.

Comment: @DavidK: I understand the issue with gimbal lock.  The underlying program converts to quaternions to perform the rotations.  It is possible to specify $\theta$ at the poles, which leads to a unique rotation vector that can be used to construct the quaternion.

Comment: I'm not convinced you understand gimbal lock, although it could be that the problem is how you explain it. (I didn't explain it well either.) It's a problem that can occur when you have full rotational capability in three dimensions; not just azimuth and elevation, but something like yaw, pitch, and roll. Two angles can't fully describe an arbitrary 3D orientation, nor can one vector. But three angles, two vectors, or one quaternion can. Gimbal lock means you used three angles but the axes for two of the angles have become the same.

Comment: @DavidK .  It seems your original note indicates it's not possible to use a spherical representation of two points that generate a unique rotation vector and unique angle to perform a rotation (allowing it to be represented as quaternions).   Regardless if that was your import, I hope I am able to create $f(p{1},p{2})$ that performs an intuitive and unique rotation. I have written up a solution, and will test and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: The problem is not generating unique rotations. Uniqueness is easy: you can get it by rotating only about the $z$ axis, for example. The problem is whether the rotations are sufficiently general and can be performed by a continuously differentiable motion. For example, with a good mounting for azimuth and elevation you can point a telescope at any part of the sky, but if you point it straight up its degrees of freedom of motion will be fundamentally and qualitatively different from when it is pointed at any other point above the horizon.

Comment: Something to ponder: given an arbitrary unit quaternion, can you represent the same rotation in your other notation?

Answer (score 1):

My answer to my question is that having an exception on a unit sphere to the poles as defined at $\phi\epsilon\{0,180\}$ as an exception makes the system worse. The purpose was to define a unique rotation vector at the poles.

1. The representation has exceptions.
2. The poles are not always at $\{0,180\}$.
3. The implementation in which I hoped to carry $\theta$ around to uniquely define theta is so complex as to make an implementation in practice indecipherable, and probably wrong.

And so I will exclusively use a spherical representation of $\{1,\theta,\phi\}$ to represent a unit sphere, and eschew the value of intuitive Cartesian coordinates to define a ray on the unit sphere.

Note, that it is not easy to explain also shows it is not a great idea.

Thanks for the responses, which lead to an answer to the question, which was essentially "is the representation usable."

Ans: NO.